# New Cylon Leader Objectives

Tags: house-rules, battlestar-galactica

When playing with a cylon leader, a benign "humans win" objective generally unbalances the game. Also, the limited number of objectives makes it fairly easy to guess which the leader has.

As a result, my group has started inventing our own objectives. Each objective card has two options, one "humans win" and one "cylons win". Generally, the "humans win" objective is slightly harder. However, both force the leader to keep the game close. Finally, each objective appears on two different cards, to better hide the info.

Sample objectives include "humans win and at least 3 people have been sent to the brig / executed" or "cylons win and resources total 19+".

Any suggestions for other objectives?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Cylon Leaders is that in general they're going to unbalance the game or have no effect, since a cylon wins in a six player game is impossible at times(especially with the CFB) The notion of each card having both a human and cylon win condition is interesting, but it could just leave you where you started by unbalancing the game if they have a choice in who wins. However creating custom agendas is not a bad idea and it is something that should be pursued. Also something to keep in mind is that you could create agendas where the CL is trying to do something and it does not matter if humans or cylons win.

Comment: Leaders can also balance the game, by having objectives which explicitly force the game to be close. We've actually found this dual-objective approach to be good at this.

Regarding agendas that don't care who wins: that is certainly an option. Do you have any specific suggestions for a good objective of this type?

Comment: Unfortunately no, since this was an idea of a friend who had some ideas but I have no way of getting in touch with him. You might be onto something, but in a 6 or 4 player game I'd pursue the cylon win and in a 5 and 7 I'd pursue a human win since that's the best odds of me winning, unless something in the game swings heavily towards completing my other objective.